# Name for functions whose outputs are larger than inputs

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a vocabulary word for functions $f$ over domain $D$ with the property:

$$\forall x \in D ~:~ f(x) \ge x$$

or for $n$ arity functions,

$$\forall x \subseteq D ~:~ \forall k \in [1 \dots n] ~:~ f(x_1,~ \dots, ~x_n) \ge x_k$$

Examples of functions where the output is never less than the input are:

- $\max$
- addition
- multiplication

over the domain of natural numbers.  A name for such functions is useful to me in order to prevent memory allocation problems in the calculation of the amount of memory a program segment requires.

Comment: I doubt there's an official name, but you could probably explain this using big O notation.

Comment: No, you can't explain this using big O.

Comment: Closest I can come up with, is monotonic functions on ordered sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  Not nescessarily.  It's possible for x < y < z  < f(y) < f(x) < f(z). Which is no monotonic.  Or is that what you meant by "on ordered sets".

Comment: see the wikipedia monotonicity only applies in that case on ordered sets.

Comment: Monotonicity doesn't apply, since for example $x^2 / 1000$ is monotonic but not satisfying.  In the absence of suggestions I think I'll go with "amplifying functions".